# Passport JS deserialize error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local, express-session

I have created a REST API on MEAN stack. I'm having issues with PassportJS's deserialize function. It seems that it's not getting called at all through the entire running context of my node app. All other functions are running fine. I have been struggling with this issue for the past two days. :( I checked all the post on StackOverflow related to Passport Auth but no help. Following is my code. What am I missing?

```
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const status = require('http-status');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = function(app) {
    var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/someDbName');
    var User = db.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({id: {type: Number,required: true,index: true}}));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {done(null, user.id);});

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findOne({id: id }).exec(done);
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ 'id': username })
            .exec(function (err, user) {
                if (user && password === user.data.password) {
                    return done(null, user);
                }
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username or Password.'});
            });
    }));

    app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'some secret' }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());  

    app.post('/api/v1/auth/user/login', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return res.
                    status(status.UNAUTHORIZED).send();
            }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.
                        status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send();
                }
                return res.
                    status(status.OK).
                    send(req.user); // req.user is set here
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });

    app.get('/api/v1/user/data', function(req, res){
        // req.user is always turning up to be undefined here
        // even though we have a session object in the req object.
        if (req.user) { 
            return res.
                status(status.ACCEPTED).
                send(req.user);
        }
        return res.status(status.UNAUTHORIZED).send();
    });
}
```

PS I'm using Passport v0.4.0 | Mongoose v4.0.3 | Express v4.16.2. | Node v6.10.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `done` with an `err` and `user` parameter

```
        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
          User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
           done(err, user);
          });
        });
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I am calling done. It is still the same. No help :(